# Statistics of static files in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've set up some static files in Google App Engine and was wondering if there's any way to track how many times users access those static files.

I've added a file like this in my app.yaml:

```
- url: /files
  static_dir: files
```

I would like to track how many downloads I have gotten, if that's possible. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Every time somebody is requesting a file (or any kind of request) Google App Engine logs it. So in theory you could write an application that does exactly that since they have the [Logs API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/functions) for it.

Otherwise you could simply check that through the dashboard of your application on

```
https://appengine.google.com/logs?app_id=s~app-name
```

and from there through the options to add some filters.